# Split String to Pair

Tags: kotlin

I try split `String` on two: `text.split("\\s+".toRegex(), 2)`. But I have no guarantees that there will be exactly two. Example: `"abc".split("\\s+".toRegex(), 2).size == 1`.

Is it possible to split `String` into two parts? Or get `Pair<String, String>`?

**Update.** Expected result:

- `"123 456 789 0"` -> `("123", "456 789 0")` or `listOf("123", "456 789 0")`
- `"123"` -> `("123", "")` or `listOf("123", "")`

Comment: What do you expect to get if there is no delimiter in an input string like `"abc"`?

Comment: @Ilya `("abc", "")` I updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not:

```
Pair(text.substringBefore(' ').trim(), text.substringAfter(' ').trim())
```

This depends, of course, on whether you want to split on *all* spaces and ignore any more than 2 strings:

```
text.split(Regex("\\s+")).let {
    Pair(it[0], it.getOrNull(1) ?: "")
}
```

or if you want to split on the *last* space (use `substringBeforeLast`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My bad I forgot about expected result. I added this to question.